# Django server not displaying the database information in the html template

Tags: django, django-views

I am trying to do an ecommerce and when creating the database it does not update in the checkout.html. page. Below the code.

`views.py`

```
def cart(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer = customer, complete = False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
    else:
        items = []
        order = {'get_cart_total':0, 'get_cart_items':0}
    context = {'items':items, 'order':order}
    return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)

def checkout(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    customer = request.user.customer
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer = customer, complete = False)
    items = order.orderitem_set.all()
else:
    items = []
    order = {'get_cart_total':0, 'get_cart_items':0}
context = {}
return render(request, 'store/checkout.html', context)
```

`checkout.html`

```
                {% for item in items %}
                <div class="cart-row">
                    <div style="flex:2"><img class="row-image" src="{{item.product.imageURL}}"></div>
                    <div style="flex:2"><p>{{item.product.name}}</p></div>
                    <div style="flex:1"><p>${{item.product.price|floatformat:2}}</p></div>
                    <div style="flex:1"><p>x{{item.quantity}}</p></div>
                </div>
                
            {% endfor %}
```

it works for cart.html but it does not work for checkout.html and there is no errors shown to look for. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context is empty. The context is a dictionary where the names of the variables used in the template map to the corresponding values.

If you thus want to pass `items` to the template, you write:

```
def checkout(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer = customer, complete = False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
    else:
        items = []
        order = {'get_cart_total':0, 'get_cart_items':0}
    # pass  items ↓    pass order ↓
    context = {'items': items, 'order': order }
    return render(request, 'store/checkout.html', context)
```

Here the `items` will be an empty queryset, since you take the `orderitem_set` of the `order`, but at that point you did not create an `OrderItem` objects that are linked to that `Order`, you thus likely should first create `OrderItem`s for the created `order`.